# How to change "journal_mode" of a Sqlite database in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, insert, sqlite-journal-mode

Following the instructions of Sqlite's [PRAGMA](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html) I found that `PRAGMA schema.journal_mode;` changes the journal_mode and given the options I chose `off` to increase performance of insert function. I wrote:

```
SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;PRAGMA Schema.journal_mode=off;");
```

which opens a database called `MyDatabase.sqlite` and the command

```
PRAGMA Schema.journal_mode=off;
```

which is written in the end, I believe turns off the journaling of the sqlite database, but I don't have a clue on how to do it and if this is the proper way then what am I doing wrong because I see no change in performance after adding the PRAGMA command.

I downloaded the Sqlite Library from a link referred in [Tigran's Blog Post on Sqlite](http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PRAGMA` keyword is not for use in connection strings.  The proper connection string syntax would be:

```
SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;journal mode=Off;");
```

One way to discover these is to use the `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder` object:

```
SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder lcb = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();
lcb.JournalMode = SQLiteJournalModeEnum.Off;
lcb.DataSource = sqlFile;
lcb.Version = 3;

string myLtConnStr = lcb.ConnectionString;
```

Result:

> "journal mode=Off;data source=\"C:\SQLite Dbs\mydata.db\";version=3"

Some DB providers have many many options -- particularly with regard to DateTime handling and options -- which can be toggled this way.  Once you know the syntax, you can elide the `ConnectionStringBuilder` object.

Comment: Note that after reading your previous question, I suspect most of the problem is with your code, not the time it takes SQLite to insert.

Comment: Yes, I found out that I didn't use being transaction method